# Today's threshold difficulty at 3,9 what would a miner need to go solo

Tags: mining-hardware, solo-mining

What i am asking is a relative threshold on the minimum Hash rate needed to mine solo, taking into account todays difficulty,could it be an ASIC of 1TH/s or 5TH/s so as to compare with pool mining

Comment: potential duplicate: [Solo Mining vs Pool Mining for users with high computing power](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/594/solo-mining-vs-pool-mining-for-users-with-high-computing-power)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no minimum power needed to mine solo. You should note, however, that if you mine solo, your rewards will be much more inconsistent than if you mine in a pool. This is the major reason why pooled mining exists.

With 5 TH/s at the current difficulty, the average time for you to find a block [is 38 days](http://www.bitcoinx.com/profit/); with 1 TH/s, 189 days. But this is a random process that would average to 38 (or 189) days, and that time period is only likely to grow larger as time goes on. You have a real chance, then, of never getting any reward for your work (the reverse is also true, of course: you have a chance of finding more than expected...but I wouldn't stake thousands of dollars on it). Personally, I'd want an expected period of no more than 10 days/block (~20 TH/s currently) to consider solo mining a good option.

Also of note: your intuition of how any [random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness) process will work out is very probably very wrong. I'd go for mining in a pool so that I don't have to deal with any large amount of randomness in this process.

Comment: For various machines to make a total of 20 TH/s as a solo miner should these be under 1 address

Comment: @user14248 No, it doesn't matter whether you use one address or various addresses. There's nothing that tracks how many hashes/second an address is running. In fact, I'd prefer various addresses to add a little anonymity.