# would 10 x 2TH/s machines give me the possibility to mine solo

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware, hashpower, solo-mining

Would 10 X 2TH/s machines give me the a heads up on pool mining or go solo mining obviously using different addresses on each machine, or one address prone to redundant work?

Comment: Even you, solving problems by hand on the paper with a speed 1 hash per day, have this possibility. Is it money-wise is debatable and offtopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tim S.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/12034/tim-s) had a [good answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/23204/14010) about this earlier today.

Since your overall hash rate is going to be around 20 TH/s, you would be OK doing your own solo mining. But with solo mining, your rewards will be a lot more inconsistent than if you mined in a pool.